# openpyxl issue: cell value deleted instead of moved

Tags: python, openpyxl

I wrote a script that is supposed to move certain cells if they fulfill a condition, but instead of moving, the values are deleted instead.

I tried running each code block separately, and they each worked fine, but when combined, the issue arose.

```
import openpyxl

removal = ['a', 'b', '-c', 'c', 'd']

for num in range (8, ws.max_row):
    for remove_item in removal:
        if (ws['A'+str(num)].value.startswith('ABC') or ws['A'+str(num)].value.startswith('DEF')) and (ws['B'+str(num)].value.startswith(remove_item) or ws['B'+str(num)].value.endswith(remove_item) or ws['C'+str(num)].value.startswith('ok')):
            ws.move_range('D'+str(num), cols=4)
            ws.move_range('E'+str(num), cols=4)
```

No error feedback. The output file removed all these items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are moving empty cells to the new range and thus overwriting your data.

```
for remove_item in removal:
    if <condition>:
        ws.move_range('D'+str(num), cols=4)
```

Since the if condition is met multiple times, you move for example range D8 4 columns, and then you move range D8 (now containing no data) 4 columns again, overwriting your previously moved data.

Comment: That's what I realized too after hours of staring at my code! Can't believe I made such a stupid mistake. My nested for loop is the one creating the issue, is there any way to avoid nested for loop to overwrite the cell values?

Comment: Add a ```break``` after the if check. This way the nested for loop will exit after the condition is met and the cell moved.

Comment: You're welcome! Could you accept my answer also to close the question?

Comment: I think I did, but let me know if it isn't showing up. Thanks again.